# How to authorize a subkey using a primary master key pair?

Tags: key-management, rsa, web-service, ecdsa

*I'm using [webcrypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API), not PGP/GPG.*

I would like to use a key pair to create a "subkey" that is authorized by my primary key in a way anyone can publicly verify so I don't need to expose the primary key's private component to any web-facing systems.

My idea is to:

- primary key signs a hash of subkeys public component
- then use the subkeys private key (proving it has access) to encrypt this signed blob

Verification would be:

- use the subkey public key to decrypt the signature
- use the primary key’s public to verify the signature.

Would this be safe? Do I need to ad any tamper protection (AHEAD/HMAC)? I'm interested in an answer for both [ECC and RSA](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto#Supported_algorithms).